# How to remove double quotes to make tuple in python from the array

Tags: python-3.x

Input is

```
["('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',10)", "('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',14)", "('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',15)"]
```

Expected output

```
[('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',10),('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',14), ('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',15)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution is to use `eval` and `map`.
Example:

```
text = ["('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',10)", "('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',14)", "('ABCD','ABCD.pdf',15)"]
out = list(map(eval, text))
```

Out contains the desired result.

See the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)